# Print a String by name recieved as the contents of a string?

Tags: c++, string, arduino

Im trying to create a system with the ability to set items displayed on an lcd using a config string.

Example:

```
String configSTRA = "A1A2B2B30000";

  String cADP1 = configSTRA.substring(0, 2);    // => "Code Pair: 1"

  String cADP2 = configSTRA.substring(2, 4);    // => "Code Pair: 2"

  String cADP3 = configSTRA.substring(4, 6);    // => "Code Pair: 3"

  String cADP4 = configSTRA.substring(6, 8);    // => "Code Pair: 4"

String A1 = ("test");

String A2 = ("12:00");

String B2 = ("[V in  ]");

String B3 = ("[V out ]"); 


lcd.print(cADP1);
```

I would like the above last cmd to print the content of String A1?
Obviously at the moment it prints A1.

Comment: Variable names are not compiled into your binary, so this is not possible. Try a map.

Comment: question is not clear .

Comment: The arduino will read a configuration string from a file on the sdcard, it will then grab the first 4 double character blocks of the code, this is the 4 corners of the display, if block 1 = A1, i would like it to print the contents of the string A1 in the first corner of the screen (Block 1),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ can't map between run-time strings and compile-time variable names. You could use a `map` to do the mapping yourself. Something like this:

```
std::map<String, String> varMap;
varMap["A1"] = "test";
varMap["A2"] = "12:00";
//...

lcd.print(varMap[cADP1]);
```

Comment: This looks like the direction i need to go, and from your example i gather that i can also include any type of var? easier to to read your example than this [C++  Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Comment: What do you mean by "include any type of var"? `varMap` in this example is a mapping from `String` to `String`. You could happily make a different map, like `std::map<String,int>` to map from `String`s to `int`s, but you can't put `int`s into `varMap`, for example.

Comment: lol, sorry, that's what i meant,  also as a note for anyone else that wants to use the map command on an Arduino, the following library is required  https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/map as the built in map command is completely diffrent

Comment: If one wants to have strings which have the value of variable or enum identifiers then the preprocessor can help a lot (look up the stringify operator, cf. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html). That can be a very powerful tool if combined with maps.